# no soundcard detected; wrong kernel audio driver

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I dont have any sound on my laptop. I think I have the wrong kernel audio driver, but dont know how to change it. I already blacklisted the audio driver in use.

Here some outputs:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i -A7 audio
```

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1025:1269]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
```

--- no soundcards ---

Already reinstalled alsa, but I can not open the alsamixer.
Thanks for help

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: uname -a
Linux ????-pc 5.3.0-45-generic #37~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 15:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux